# Missing lines in pdf print taken on Linux

Tags: linux, pdf, printing

When printing a PDF document on Linux some horizontal and vertical lines go missing. The document contains many lines of the same width but only a few go missing each time.
The same document when printed on windows works fine.
I have tried Acroread version 7.0 on Linux and it works fine. But with acroread version 8 I can't get my document to print properly. Is there any workaround or solution to get this working

Comment: Which Linux distro? Have you tried `evince`?

Comment: Update your version of Adobe Reader; the latest is 9.x. Or try a different viewer.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "printing a PDF document on Linux"? Did you use Acrobat Reader for Linux or another tool like Okular or evince?
The Portable Document Format is a complex format and it is quite likely that the file you are trying to print is either not properly supported in your PDF viewer or not correctly encoded in the PDF file itself (file is damaged or not well-formed).

My recommendation would be to try different tools to see if they manage to handle the file better. Apart from Adobe's official Reader for Linux, there are different tools which use the Poppler library, for example Okular (KDE) or evince (Gnome). Finally, you have Ghostscript, which has a command line tool (gs) to render both PostScript and PDF files into bitmap images, so you could render your PDF file into a PNG or TIFF file and print this one.

There are also some scripts/programs using Ghostscript or Poppler to convert between PDF and PostScript (e.g. ps2pdf, pdf2ps, pdftops), so you can try to convert your PDF to PostScript and then back to PDF. This helps sometimes as well.

Comment: I am using Acrobat Reader on Linux and trying to print directly from it.

Comment: The tool shouldn't matter, it just sends the (presumably original) file to the printing system. Check what `lpr mangled.pdf` does. Check the printing setup, it might be an incorrect/outdated PPD file, or some other configuration screwup.